# Can my application change user's browser settings?

Tags: javascript, browser

Is possible to do so that my Applications can modify the user's browser settings ?

For example, if i want my application to disable user's Firefox update, or to check if he has an plugin installed and if he doesn't offer him to download it, etc.

Comment: The potential to abuse this would be massive, so no, definitely not.

Comment: *Hopefully not.* Offering a plugin, maybe yes. Changing update settings: GOD NO. It's not for your random website to decide how anyone's browser is updated.

Comment: Yep, the answer ends up being the obvious, thanks you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, no you cannot change browser settings, with a few [exceptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserSettings).

However, using the [management API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/management) you can check to see what add-ons are installed. Although it's not clear to me if it includes plugins.

You wouldn't be able to install the add-on, but you could at least open it's webpage if needed.